# Quickstart Instructions for Speech to Text. Help to understand

Tags: google-cloud-speech

google-cloud-speech

It seems very simple to use the speech to text option in this google cloud service. I am not a programmer, and I am mystified.  I am usually pretty good with tech.  I would appreciate it if someone could help me through this:

"Set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the path of the JSON file that contains your service account key."

I have done everything else, project set up, but where do I find this. I am lost.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to :

1. Create  a service account
2. Generate the key file (`key.json`)
3. Provide authentication credentials to your application code by setting the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="key.json"`

> Setting the environment variable allows you to provide credentials
> separately from your application, without making changes to
> application code when you deploy. Alternately, you can explicitly
> specify the path to the service account key file in your code. For
> more information, see Authenticating as a service account.

[Getting started with authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#command-line)